# How to use routing with flowbite-react

Tags: reactjs, flowbite

I'm trying to start using flowbite to use they inbuilt components, I already had a small application which was configured something like this for routing:

This is my main.jsx file.

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
import App from './App';
import './main.css';
import Expenses from './routes/expenses';
import Invoice from './routes/invoice';
import Invoices from './routes/invoices';


ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("app")).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter>
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<App />}>
        <Route path="/expenses" element={<Expenses />} />
        <Route path="/invoices" element={<Invoices />}>
          <Route
            index
            element={
              <main style={{ padding: '1rem' }}>
                <p>Select an invoice</p>
              </main>
            }
          />
          <Route path=":invoiceId" element={<Invoice />} />
        </Route>
        <Route
          path="*"
          element={
            <main style={{ padding: '1rem' }}>
              <p>There's nothing here!</p>
            </main>
          }
        />
      </Route>
    </Routes>
  </BrowserRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

And in this is my App.jsx file:

```js
import { Accordion, Avatar, Dropdown, Navbar } from "flowbite-react";
import { NavbarCollapse } from "flowbite-react/lib/esm/components/Navbar/NavbarCollapse";
import * as React from "react";
import { Outlet, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import profileImage from "./assets/profile-picture-3.jpg";

export default function App() {
  // set the target element that will be collapsed or expanded (eg. navbar menu)
  const targetEl = document.getElementById("targetEl");

  
  return (
    
<Navbar
  fluid={true}
  rounded={true}
>
  <Navbar.Brand href="https://flowbite.com/">
    <img
      src="https://flowbite.com/docs/images/logo.svg"
      className="mr-3 h-6 sm:h-9"
      alt="Flowbite Logo"
    />
    <span className="self-center whitespace-nowrap text-xl font-semibold dark:text-white">
      Flowbite
    </span>
  </Navbar.Brand>
  <div className="flex md:order-2">
    <Dropdown
      arrowIcon={false}
      inline={true}
      label={<Avatar alt="User settings" img="https://flowbite.com/docs/images/people/profile-picture-5.jpg" rounded={true}/>}
    >
      <Dropdown.Header>
        <span className="block text-sm">
          Bonnie Green
        </span>
        <span className="block truncate text-sm font-medium">
          name@flowbite.com
        </span>
      </Dropdown.Header>
      <Dropdown.Item>
        Dashboard
      </Dropdown.Item>
      <Dropdown.Item>
        Settings
      </Dropdown.Item>
      <Dropdown.Item>
        Earnings
      </Dropdown.Item>
      <Dropdown.Divider />
      <Dropdown.Item>
        Sign out
      </Dropdown.Item>
    </Dropdown>
    <Navbar.Toggle />
  </div>
  <Navbar.Collapse>
    <Navbar.Link
      href="/navbars"
      active={true}
    >
      Home
    </Navbar.Link>
    <Navbar.Link href="/expenses">
      Patients
    </Navbar.Link>
    <Navbar.Link href="/navbars">
      Services
    </Navbar.Link>
    <Navbar.Link href="/navbars">
      Pricing
    </Navbar.Link>
    <Navbar.Link href="/navbars">
      Contact
    </Navbar.Link>
  </Navbar.Collapse>
</Navbar>

    // <div>
    //   <h1>Bookkeeper</h1>
    //   <nav style={{ borderBottom: 'solid 1px', paddingBottom: '1rem' }}>
    //     <Link to="/invoices">Invoices</Link> |{' '}
    //     <Link to="/expenses">Expenses</Link>
    //   </nav>
    //   <Outlet />
    // </div>
  );
}
```

I made the changes to "route" to /expenses, and my project reloads or something but is never showing anything on screen, so... not sure how flowbite works for routing, can anybody help me please?

Answer (score 0):

Oh, sorry, forget it, I was missing to add the  tag at the end of my navigation bar, so, here is how the code should be:

```js
import { Accordion, Avatar, Dropdown, Navbar } from "flowbite-react";
import { NavbarCollapse } from "flowbite-react/lib/esm/components/Navbar/NavbarCollapse";
import * as React from "react";
import { Outlet, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import profileImage from "./assets/profile-picture-3.jpg";

export default function App() {
  // set the target element that will be collapsed or expanded (eg. navbar menu)
  const targetEl = document.getElementById("targetEl");

  return (
    <nav>
      <Navbar fluid={true} rounded={true}>
        <Navbar.Brand href="https://flowbite.com/">
          <img
            src="https://flowbite.com/docs/images/logo.svg"
            className="mr-3 h-6 sm:h-9"
            alt="Flowbite Logo"
          />
          <span className="self-center whitespace-nowrap text-xl font-semibold dark:text-white">
            Flowbite
          </span>
        </Navbar.Brand>
        <div className="flex md:order-2">
          <Dropdown
            arrowIcon={false}
            inline={true}
            label={
              <Avatar
                alt="User settings"
                img="https://flowbite.com/docs/images/people/profile-picture-5.jpg"
                rounded={true}
              />
            }
          >
            <Dropdown.Header>
              <span className="block text-sm">Bonnie Green</span>
              <span className="block truncate text-sm font-medium">
                name@flowbite.com
              </span>
            </Dropdown.Header>
            <Dropdown.Item>Dashboard</Dropdown.Item>
            <Dropdown.Item>Settings</Dropdown.Item>
            <Dropdown.Item>Earnings</Dropdown.Item>
            <Dropdown.Divider />
            <Dropdown.Item>Sign out</Dropdown.Item>
          </Dropdown>
          <Navbar.Toggle />
        </div>
        <Navbar.Collapse>
          <Navbar.Link href="/navbars" active={true}>
            Home
          </Navbar.Link>
          <Navbar.Link href="/expenses">Patients</Navbar.Link>
          <Navbar.Link href="/navbars">Services</Navbar.Link>
          <Navbar.Link href="/navbars">Pricing</Navbar.Link>
          <Navbar.Link href="/navbars">Contact</Navbar.Link>
        </Navbar.Collapse>
      </Navbar>
      <Outlet />
    </nav>
  );
}
```